# In Android, how can I implement text where some of the words have touch listeners to detect tap and hold-down gestures?

Tags: android, listener, cpu-word, gesture

I would like to implement text where some words in the text have listeners for both tap and hold-down gestures. What is the best way of doing this? An example would be extremely helpful

Comment: For tap use onClickListener on textView

Answer (score 1):

The best way is [ClickableSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html). Remember to use `TextView.setLinksClickable(true);`